# Yii get ajax request ID

Tags: php, ajax, yii, ajax-request

When you create an ajax button like

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
    'Submit request',
    array('logInOfficeEmp/update&id='.$model->id),
    array(
        'replace'=>'#req_res02',
        array('id' => 'inside_popup') // how to retrieve this
    )
);
```

How to retrieve the ID in the controller, note that you get to know it's ajax or not using `Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest()`

Comment: do you want to retrive the id?

Comment: yes, someone edited the question and removed it :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as follows:

```
<?= CHtml::ajaxButton('Click', $this->createUrl('path/here', array('myparam' => 'test)), array('success' => 'js:function(){alert("test");}'), array('class' => 'cssclasses'))?>
```

It will then be available in `$_POST['myparam']`

Comment: Typo? 'success' => 'function(){alert("test");}' should probably read 'success' => 'js:function(){alert("test");}'